# How to generate v1 signature certificate for Android App Bundle?

Tags: android, google-play

I'm developing an Android App signed with v1 + v2 signature certificate for a long time, now I want to publish it to Google Play, but according to the latest policy, Google Play doesn't allow APK format anymore, I have to build Android App Bundle, and as far as I know AAB only support signed with v1 signature certificate, how can I generate a v1 certificate for the AAB which it could also has compatible with the old certificate?

Answer (score 1):

You can use apksigner found in %ANDROID_HOME%/sdk/build-tools/24.0.3/ (the .jar is in the /lib subfolder) to sign APKs/AABs

```
apksigner sign --ks my.keystore my-app.aab --ks-key-alias alias_name
```

But dont just sign with v1 as its deprecated and apps signed with v1
fail to install on android 11 and above

> APK Signature Scheme v2 now required
>
> Apps that target Android 11 (API level 30) that are currently only
> signed using APK Signature Scheme v1 must now also be signed using APK
> Signature Scheme v2 or higher. Users can't install or update apps that
> are only signed with APK Signature Scheme v1 on devices that run
> Android 11.
>
> To verify that your app is being signed with APK Signature Scheme v2
> or higher, you can use either Android Studio, or the apksigner tool on
> the command line. Caution: To support devices that run older versions
> of Android, you should continue to sign your APKs using APK Signature
> Scheme v1, in addition to signing your APK with APK Signature Scheme
> v2 or higher.
> https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/behavior-changes-11#minimum-signature-scheme